# Laravel Spatie - Why does the [object Object] are being displayed not its exact value from database?

Tags: php, json, laravel, activitylog

I am using Spatie for logging activities in my web site. I created a table where the data from activity_log database table will be displayed. There's no problem in retrieving the data from database but my problem is that whenever I display the values from `properties` column it only displays `[object Object]`.

Here's what the data table looks like:

[image]

While it's actual values in the database table of `activity_log` is this:

[image]

Here's my snippet code from my controller:

```
public function datatable_Activities()
{
    $data = Activity::all()->where('causer_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
    return Datatables::of($data)->make(true);
}
```

Snippet code for displaying the data in my blade file:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#activity_table_log").DataTable({
      responsive:true,
      processing:true,
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      stateSave:false,
      scrollY:true,
      scrollX:true,
      ajax:"{{route('datatable_Activities')}}",
      order:[0, 'desc'],
      columns:[
        {data:'log_name', name: 'log_name'},
        {data:'description', name: 'description'},
        {data:'subject_id', name: 'subject_id'},
        {data:'properties', name: 'properties'},
        {data:'created_at', name: 'created_at', searchable: false, sortable:false},
      ]
    });
  });
</script>
```

> I already tried `json_decode()` but unfortunately it is not working..
>   How to display it properly like the values stored in `properties`
>   column in database not the `[object Object]`?

**However** when I check the response in Developer's Tool it retrieves the values of properties exactly from the database.

Here's the example nested JSON object I am trying to put in the data table:

```
{
"id":6,
   "log_name":"PurchaseH",
   "description":"A purchase h has been updated",
   "subject_id":1,
   "subject_type":"App\\Model\\Purchase\\PurchaseH",
   "causer_id":1,
   "causer_type":"App\\User",
   "properties":{
      "attributes":{
         "total":1250000
      },
      "old":{
         "total":null
      }
   },
   "created_at":"2020-06-14T09:04:34.000000Z",
   "updated_at":"2020-06-14T09:04:34.000000Z"
},
```

P.S. I'm Using latest Google chrome, Laravel Framework and Spatie.

Comment: Did you try to decode it using the second param for the "assoc" to be true?`json_decode($properties, true);` ? Also, when you pass the $properties to the Datatable, try casting it to array by using `$properties->toArray()` and see if that works.

Comment: also, that doesn't work, you should check this link: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/50304/datatable-is-showing-object-object-in-columns

Comment: yes i tried json_decode with second param as true but still does not work.. apparently as I searched more I figured out that this is a nested JSON object...

Comment: I included the example nested JSON object... also the tried the link you provided but still no luck